# ASP.NET Core 8.0 Identity API endpoints: Why antiforgery is not enabled?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-identity, .net-8.0

Identity API endpoints are introduced in ASP.NET Core 8.0. I'm trying to use them in my Web API project. It looks like the endpoints do not require antiforgery token validation.

How can I enable antiforgery tokens for these endpoints?

Comment: "IAntiforgery provides the API to configure antiforgery features" You can have a look at [Generate antiforgery tokens with IAntiforgery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-8.0#generate-antiforgery-tokens-with-iantiforgery)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue the following way:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapGroup("/api/user")
    .MapIdentityApi<User>()
    //.WithMetadata(new RequireAntiforgeryTokenAttribute()) // Doesn't work; why?
    .AddEndpointFilter(routeHandlerFilter: async (context, next) =>
    {
        if (!"TRACE,OPTIONS,HEAD,GET".Split(',').Contains(context.HttpContext.Request.Method))
        {
            var antiForgery = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IAntiforgery>();
            await antiForgery.ValidateRequestAsync(context.HttpContext);
        }
        return await next(context);
    });
    endpoints.MapControllers().WithMetadata(new RequireAntiforgeryTokenAttribute());
});
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**